# Keep values blocked by Excel unsafe link warning popup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sharepoint, excel-2010, excel-2019

I have an excel report generated (and uploaded to Sharepoint) by an engineer that has a plugin that performs calcs and populates cells with values from calculations. Problem is that he has the plugin to read the values, and I don't. The engineer is on vacation for 4 weeks, and I'd like to present the report tomorrow to the team.

Each time I open the spreadsheet on my PC, the values I desire appear, is instantly blocked, followed by an annoying popup warning me about the links being unsafe. Regardless of what selection I make (Update, Don't Update) the spreadsheet updates and floods the cells with the classical annoying "#name$" broken links strings in every cell containing the values I do want to preserve.

Is there a way I can suppress the link warning popup and preserve the juicy values that is grayed and blocked by the form?

Answer (score -2):

Found a means to retreive the raw values from the spreadsheet without having to disable the popup, go to source (which was NOT another spreadsheet), go to the Advance section and toggle prompting, or bother the engineer while he was out of the country, not on holiday leave mind you, but addressing a family emergency.

Solution for those of us imperfect humans who don't have crystal balls and plan perfectly 100% of the time like some people on this thread, and get caught in the same pickle.

1. Download linked spreadsheet, save to folder - Don't open it.
2. Open another blank spreadsheet
3. Upload data from the downloaded spreadsheet with the embedded links
4. Viola ~ Raw data in tabular format
5. Remove filter
6. Copy-Paste unto self as Values
7. Save new spreadsheet

Congratulations - Crisis overted ;)